two columns concat in pandas dataframe
How to concat two columns in a dataframe so that the data goes in the order in which they went in the column and also remove unnecessary characters so that only numeric characters remain.
For example i have dataframe:
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {
    'id_part1': ['1221002', 'Johny Cash', '2-12-0032', 2112],
    'id_part2': ['', '345000223', '', 4322],
    'created_date': ['2019-01-01', '15/02/2016', '2013-05-07', '2020-08-29']})

dataframe
I need to get the following result:
result

How does this generalize? Do you always have empty strings in id_part2? what if you have non-numeric in both columns?

Do you always have empty rows in id_part2? – Yes, or it could be the other way around: id_part1 is empty, but id_part2 is filled.
What if you have non-numeric in both columns? - This can't be.

One option is to create a new id by removing any non-digit characters in both columns before joining.
df['correct_id'] = df[['id_part1', 'id_part2']].astype(str).apply(lambda x: int(''.join(x.str.replace(r'\D', '', regex=True))), axis=1)

print(df[['correct_id', 'created_date']])
    correct_id  created_date
0      1221002    2019-01-01
1    345000223    15/02/2016
2      2120032    2013-05-07
3     21124322    2020-08-29

Also consider formating your date column
df['created_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_date'], format='mixed')

print(df[['correct_id', 'created_date']])
    correct_id  created_date
0      1221002    2019-01-01
1    345000223    2016-02-15
2      2120032    2013-05-07
3     21124322    2020-08-29


Awesome answer! +1
